# Building new version of a table and replacing the old one by rename, is it a good idea?

Tags: sql-server

We have a slightly heavy table which is semi-frequently (every ~5 minute) being recreated by a procedure. I wondered if there was something that could be done in order to minimize the downtime during the table rebuild, and have thought of two possibilities so far (let's call the table "Device"):

**Option A**
1) Create the new table in the procedure, name it `Device_new`
2) Rename old table from `Device` to `Device_old`
3) Rename new table from `Device_new` to `Device`

**Option B**
Same as Option A, except do it using Partition Switching.
*Caveat*: Partition switching is significantly more complex to setup, and has quite strict requirements for usage.

Are these options poor solutions, if yes, how would you solve this use-case? Thank you.

Comment: Although I can't comment on the speed differential between the options, I would note that the typical method SSMS uses when scripting out design changes to tables is the same as your option A. In my experience doing that on large tables, the momentary outage while the rename occurs is negligible.  @Dan Guzman's idea looks very nice though - if milliseconds matter to you then it would be useful to do a side by side speed comparison on a quiet server of the different options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mentioned that partition switching is more complex but that is not the case when the table is not partitioned.  One can use `SWITCH` to efficiently replace the entire contents of one non-partitioned table with another as a meta-data only operation.  The requirement for `SWITCH` is that the source and target table must have the same schema, indexes, constraints, and be storage aligned.  These requirements are presumably the same as the rename technique so the effort is similar.

Note that unlike table partitioning with a partition function and scheme, `SWITCH` of a non-partitioned table can be used in any SQL Server edition.

Below is a sample DDL script for option B:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Device(
      DeviceID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Device PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ON [PRIMARY]
    , DeviceName varchar(30) NOT NULL
    );
CREATE INDEX idx_Device_DeviceName ON dbo.Device(DeviceName) ON [PRIMARY];
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Device_new(
      DeviceID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Device_new PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ON [PRIMARY]
    , DeviceName varchar(30) NOT NULL
    );
CREATE INDEX idx_Device_new_DeviceName ON dbo.Device_new(DeviceName) ON [PRIMARY];
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.RefreshDevice
AS

SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRY

    TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.Device_new;

    --load dbo.Device_new with new data here

    BEGIN TRAN;

    TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.Device;

    ALTER TABLE dbo.Device_new
        SWITCH TO dbo.Device;

    COMMIT;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;

    THROW;

END CATCH;
GO
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I had no idea the SWITCH-statement could be used outside a partitioned-table scenario. Great!

Comment: @krystah, glad it helped.  I added a note to my answer that `SWITCH` can also be used in editions other than enterprise.